# How to use .NetCore 1.0 and IdentityServer3 together?

Tags: validation, security, asp.net-core, access-token, identityserver3

I am trying to make my application work with our IdentityServer3. The unsolvable to me seems that there is no IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation package for .NetCore. I have to validate the token (other software works in that manner, but using .NetFramework with no trouble), what are my options or perhaps I didn't research properly?

I would really love to see

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "https://identity.identityserver.io",
    RequiredScopes = new[] { "api1", "api2" }
});
```

Comment: for .net core you need to use identityserver4

Comment: is it absolute and there is no way to do it with identityserver3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Asp.Net Core use [IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation). Just grab it via your NuGet package manager. Remember IDS3 and IDS4 are just implementations of a common set of protocols. Your OP can be written in Asp.Net Core (eg with IDS4) and your WebApi can still be using MVC5 (using IDS3 AccessTokenValidation) and vice versa scenario applies. In the IDS4 version of this middleware you will need to use `ScopeName` and `AdditionalScopes` to achieve your goals

Comment: Those were my initial thoughts, and I went to NuGet package manager to check for it before asking the question; however, there wasn't any IDS4 packages. I tried to manually bring it by modified project.json and it worked like a charm with few lines of code and a bit different syntax, thank you

Comment: Yeah, it's just confusing having `IdentityServer4` as a prefix of that package. Actually, it's just a dotnet standard compliant version of Access Token middleware.

Comment: @ZeroCool Did you manage to find a solution? If yes, will you share it?